# Json @JsonIgnore . How to ignore deeper?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

So, I am making a project that has a class Save which contains List of GameField class. To save "Save" to DB(with Hibernate).

I'm using JSON and it works pretty good, but it is parsing all fields from GameField , which makes Json String about 600 characters long. Beacuse it is so long , I am getting org.hibernate.exception.DataException which says that size of String is too big.

I was trying to increase avalible space in database to properly store that big String but it didn't work.

So i have found @JsonIgnore and @JsonIgnoreProperties annotations to stop Json from parsing few fields. It worked but only for Save class not for GameField.

Is it possible to prevent Json from parsing any fields that i want?

Here is Save class:

```
public class Save {
    private List<GameField> fields;
    // getters setters , etc.
}
```

Game Field:

```
public class GameField {

    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean isSet;

    private char fieldSign;

    @JsonIgnore
    private final int numberInArray;
}
```

Fragment of parsing code:

```
public String getEncodedSaveInString(Save save) throws JsonProcessingException {
    mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(save);
}
```

Piece of User class

```
    @Entity
    public class User {
    @Column(name = "Save")
    private Save save;
}
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: I don't see any code in your example where you use `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties`.

Comment: Fixed that. I was also trying with @JsonIgnoreProperties({"isSet","numberInArray"}) , but it has no impact.

Comment: I have very similar code that works just fine. Are you using the annotation(s) from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation`?

Comment: Yes, that one. When i use only @JsonIgnore above field nothing happens. Same with @JsonIgnoreProperties() above class declaration. I am currently mixing them and hoping that it will work :D

Comment: If you are using Jackson, double-check, that everything comes from the same packages. They switched from org.codehaus.jackson to com.fasterxml.jackson and it can happen that you have both in your dependencies.

Comment: Packages are ok... Everything is from com.fasterxml.jackson. But everytime , when I parse Save class , String looks like : "{fields":[{"fieldSign":"\u0000"."set":false,"nr""0}, etc

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i found a solution. Only thing i needed to do was putting @JsonIgnore annotation above field setter. Placing it above field itself was not working

Working sample of code:

```
private Foo foo;

@JsonIgnore
public void setfoo(Foo newFoo){ this.foo = newFoo;}
```

That works fine :)